# Finding nil when reading from database

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When trying to read from Firebase I get

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Code for reading the database:

```
ref = Database.database().reference().child("userDatabases").child(userID!).child("-Lk__eup2Z7WR-iqtXkI").child("-Lk__gmhOTWfVzEPVo2t")    

    ref?.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {

                  let dict = child.value as? [String : AnyObject] ?? [:]

                    self.objectProducer.append(dict["objectProducer"] as! String)
                    self.objectType.append(dict["objectType"] as! String)
                    self.objectAmount.append(dict["amount"] as! String)
                    self.objectMeasureUnit.append(dict["unit"] as! String)
                }
            })
```

If I try to print for example: `print(dict["objectProducer"])` I get the correct result.

The FirebaseStructure I´m trying to read from looks like this:

```
 "-Lk__eup2Z7WR-iqtXkI" : {
          "-Lk__gmhOTWfVzEPVo2t" : {
            "5740700998485" : {
              "amount" : "330",
              "objectProducer" : "Coca Cola",
              "objectType" : "Zero",
              "unit" : "Milliliter"
            },
            "createdOn" : "24-7-2019 at: 22:5:35",
            "listID" : "-Lk__gmhOTWfVzEPVo2t",
            "name" : "Test"
          },
```

What is going wrong here?

Comment: I think child(userID!).child(-Lk__eup2Z7WR-iqtXkI).child(-Lk__gmhOTWfVzEPVo2t)  need to be strings. child(userID!).child("-Lk__eup2Z7WR-iqtXkI").child("-Lk__gmhOTWfVzEPVo2t")

Comment: @108g I'm sorry for being unclear. They are strings. They are being passed from the previous `UIViewController` as strings, and put in to variables.  I just replaced them with a value(`childByAutoID`) so the path of the reading should be clear for the purpose of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my opinion, change this line of code

```
let dict = child.value as? [String : AnyObject] ?? [:]
```

to:

```
guard let dict = child.value as? [String: AnyObject] else { return }
```

then you sould not getting error.

hop this help.

Comment: This worked. But I'm not sure I understand why it crashed in the first place? The values I'm asking for is clearly there.

Comment: because your dict values can be nil, so when you use nil value like this.
self.objectProducer.append(dict["objectProducer"] as! String)
program will crash every time. everytime you should check that value with optional chaining. its ok now bro ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the crash due to `self.objectAmount.append(dict["amount"] as! String)`. 
You try execute the code:  `self.objectAmount.append(dict["amount"] as! Int)`